# Convert wpf application to wpf browser application

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to convert wpf desktop application to wpf browser application? I want to make my application run from browser.

Answer (score 4):

According to my experience there is no converter available which converts WPF to XBAP.

But I did work with multiple platforms together several time in my project. I do maintain 3 platforms together WPF, Silverlight and XBAP in a single solution having single code base. I keep a common code-base and share files between 3 platforms. To achieve this I suggest you to create a Hello world XBAP application and run it first. You need to have few basic idea about how an XBAP application works. Initially understanding the entry and exit point of the application will be enough for you. Try adding one button in Page and understand how it works. Once it’s done then try to link the existing project files (XAML and CS) one by one into the XBAP project. Understand what you are adding and why are you adding. Yes it's quite a hard work you need to do. But don’t worry XBAP, WPF XAML & C# codes are almost similar. You need to know that Conditional compilation symbols can be set in project properties. So that you will be allowed to write **#if XBAP** & **#endif** statement in your code sometimes, because few classes or features may not be supported in XBAP and you need to write specific code for XBAP. As an example Dropshadow related features are not available in XBAP.

Hope this answers your query!